# Kafka Topic Rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka

I've a problem on kafka message consuming. For some topics it's unable to consume due to partition problem. So I want to delete all topics and recreate them with less partitions and they will have a same name. Is it possible or since topic name is same will partitions size on kafka reamin also same? I'm managing partitions size with spring boot kafka application yaml file.

I have tried to restart kafka but still same issue. I equalized partition size in kafka and application yaml which was different before.

Comment: You can, but you will lose all data if you don't copy them over through an intermediate topic or so, and most of the time, more partitions is better if you're not going too overboard. It's also usually not a good idea to let the client create the topics unless for local testing.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting topics is asynchronous operation while it removes log segments. Re-creating immediately with the same name may cause problems.

Besides, you want to preserve existing data, you need to instead mirror the topics within the cluster to a topic with a different name, but smaller partition count.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with the first part. The only pb you could face when recreating a topic (delete+create) is when one of the kafka server that host some partitions of this topic is down, unless, the kafka broker mark immedialtely all partitions with a to_delete flag. but for the second part I totally agree (a simple stream or consumer/producer to transfert the data before deleting)

Comment: Yes, there can be problems. One example - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14337

Comment: Ah ok, it's on the new version of Kafka, using dots as topic's name separator